# Is it possible to handle client and browser connections in a single application?

Tags: java, sockets, jsp

Let me explain my question, I couldn't find a proper way to express what I mean.

So I've created a Java socket server, and a client for it, which can communicate without any issue. I'd like to extend the server to be able to communicate with a webpage designed for this purpose, it has all the inputs the client application does, it's written in JSP and everything seems to be fine.

However, I'd like to ask if it's possible to sort of "embed" the JSP server into my socket server? Like this:
- A connection is identified through the server socket, and it accepts it.
- Then, in some way, it should determine if the received connection is from the client application, or the browser page.
- Finally, it should handle the requests in different ways, also send responses in a different format.

So basically can I do this in one application, or I have to write the handling in a JSP page, and then that page will "fake" a client, which connects to the server and receives a response?

Comment: You can use websocket in your JSP to connect to your server. And your server can differentiate the websocket connection from the non-websocket one and handle accordingly. It will be a lot easier if you use Netty on your server. https://keyholesoftware.com/2015/03/16/netty-a-different-kind-of-websocket-server/

Answer (score 0):

Essentially client application and browser are the same things. The browser just shows HTML's as page and handles basically HTTP requests.

Since your issue is quite abstract (you said that you have implemented pure sockets, which is essentially - [Transport layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer)) it is hard to provide you exact solution, but here are two ideas:

1) Client application *could* use different application protocol, i.e. your own. While browser will use HTTP one.

2) If client is also using HTTP requests, the only one way to distinguish them - is analysis of [`User-Agent` header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

Comment: I forgot to mention that communication between client and server is done as the client sends a JSONArray, the first element of the array is a JSONObject, which contains a serialized information of the client, such as IP address, MAC address, unique ID, and the second element is also a special object serialized, a sort of "request" which the server will parse and execute. EDIT (pressed enter accidentally): I think I'll parse what the browser sends in some way, and by that, I can start to handle it differently. Are there libraries available to parse raw HTTP requests?

Comment: So `User-Agent` header is your bullet